# shiny not opening in browser from RStudio

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I have created one `ui.R` and `server.R` files for very basic testing of `Shiny`.

When I execute `runApp()` from `RStudio`, another `RStudio window` opens with the `Shiny front page`.

It only goes to `Chrome` browser when I click on `open in browser` tab in that new window.

I tried discussing with some experts but as per them there is a proxy issue with my network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dropdown menu in RStudio, right next to Run App button, change it to *Run External*.

[image]

Or we can set *launch.browser*:

```
runApp(launch.browser = TRUE)
```

> **launch.browser** If true, the system’s default web browser will be
>   launched automatically after the app is started. Defaults to true in
>   interactive sessions only. This value of this parameter can also be a
>   function to call with the application’s URL.